# Unable to setup Github access from AWS EMR Jupyterhub notebooks

Tags: github, amazon-emr, jupyterhub

We are thinking of using AWS EMR Jupyterhub for a startup project with big data needs  (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-jupyterhub.html).
As we are evaluating this for a team of data-scientists to use. It is not clear how we can access the individual notebooks in the EMR Jupyterhub. Can someone point out how to access a single notebook and then all we want is to checkin our notebooks to github as they are developed. Is that possible from the AWS EMR to checkin into github?